# Plotting R² values against maxdepths (from 1 to 20) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I  have a dataframe with 20 columns and 50 rows, the 20 columns are equivalent to maxdepth 1 to 20 from a decision tree model, and the 50 rows are R² values that I got after doing error measurements for each maxdepth. I want to plot depth of decision tree (1 to 20, x - axis) against R² (accuracy, y axis).
I tried to used ggplot but I am not sure what arguments to use for x a y in the geom_line() function.
Any suggestion?

rSquaresDf #data frame 20 columns x 50 rows

ggplot(data = rSquaresDf) +
geom_line(aes(x=, y=))

Comment: Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and update your post accordingly. You'll get a higher quality of help more quickly if you include some data that allows people to post working code in response to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not good at ggplot2, but I think:

```
ggplot(rSquaresDf, aes(x =, y =)) + 
geom_line()
```

should work. That is move the "aes"-part from `geom_line()` to `ggplot()`.

**EDIT:**
Heres an example of code that should work, if you wish to plot the average R^2 against the maxdepth:

```
dat = data.frame('max_depth' = 1:20, 
             'avg_R2' = sapply(1:20, function(y){mean(rSquaresDf[,y])}))
ggplot(data = dat,aes(max_depth,avg_R2)) +
      geom_line()
```

Comment: Hi Qwethm, I used your suggestion but it threw this error:
Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
My problem is that I am not sure what to put on x and y

Comment: What exactly do you want as x- and y-values? As i understand you want your x to be a vector of numbers 1 to 20. But I'm confused by your y-values, since as I understand you have 50 y-values for each x-value.
So what do you put to the right of  the "="-signs in aes?

Comment: If you wish to plot the level against the average R^2 for the level, consider my example.

Comment: Qwethm your example worked for me, thanks a lot. I didn't have any idea about that sapply() function, it solved all my problem. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad to hear. Just beware, that what my code is plotting is the average over ALL 50 R^2-values for each max_depth-value. You could easily change this to the median, minimum or maximum for example or another statistic by simply replacing `mean` inside `sapply` with another constant.